# How to change self in a block like instance_eval method do?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, self

instance_eval method change self in its block, eg:

```
class D; end
d = D.new
d.instance_eval do
  puts self  # print something like #<D:0x8a6d9f4>, not 'main'!
end
```

If we define a method ourself(or any other methods(other than instance_eval) which takes a block), when print self, we will get 'main', which is different from instance_eval method.eg:

```
[1].each do |e|
  puts self  # print 'main'
end
```

How can i define a method(which takes a block) like instance_eval? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What to do you want to achieve?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do what you want. Probably because it'd be too confusing if you could change self yourself.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can write a method that accepts a proc argument, and then pass that as a proc argument to instance_eval.

```
class Foo
  def bar(&b)
    # Do something here first.
    instance_eval &b
    # Do something else here afterward, call it again, etc.
  end
end
```

Foo.new.bar { puts self }

Yields

```
#<Foo:0x100329f00>
```

Comment: I understand what you mean, but not solved my problem. i want to define a method like instance_eval instead of using instance_eval. I want implementation not a wrapper.Thank you all the same!

Comment: You'll need to be more specific about what you want to achieve, then. If you simply want a method that can accept a block, and then execute it one or more times within the the same context as your method, then this does that. If I had to guess, perhaps you want to pass arguments to the block as well? I know that's possible because RSpec does it, and it's true that this example does not. I should take a look at the RSpec code, and see how they do it.

Comment: Actualy, I see that RSpec doesn't pass params to block, and it uses instance_eval to call blocks. See http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/Example#run-instance_method and click "View Source".

Comment: I'm a Chinese, i can't express myself well in English! Actually i want to know the implementation detail of instance_eval, may be it cannot implemented by pure ruby, maybe only C can achieve the goal(change a block context in which it is evaluated).I will close the question soon if there is no appropriate answers.

Comment: I still can't see why it's more useful to re-implement instance_eval than to simply obtain its behavior by invoking it. If you want to see how anything in Ruby is implemented, a good place to start is at apidock.com/ruby. Find the method you're interested in (http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/instance_eval in this case), and click "Show Source". Sure enough, this method's implementation is in C, so you'll need to download source code for Ruby to explore further.

Answer (score 3):

It's obvious:

```
class Object
  def your_method(*args, &block)
    instance_eval &block
  end
end

receiver = Object.new

receiver.your_method do
  puts self  #=> it will print the self of receiver
end
```

Comment: Sorry, what i want is a method which takes a block and in that block self is changed to receiver, just like instance_eval!