# instance_eval doesn't work as expected

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to build a tinny DSL using the approach that Russ Olsen exposes in his book, Eloquent Ruby. However it is not working for me. Let's consider the following code:

```
class SayHello
  def initialize
    @message = "Hello."
    instance_eval(yield) if yield
  end

  def say_it
    puts @message
  end
end

SayHello.new { say_it }
```

The error I get is:

```
say_hello.rb:12:in `block in <main>': undefined local variable or method `say_it' for main:Object (NameError)
    from say_hello.rb:4:in `initialize'
    from say_hello.rb:12:in `new'
    from say_hello.rb:12:in `<main>'
```

But... when you use `instance_eval` method, the value of `self` shouldn't be assigned to the object that calls the method?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the block runs, you want `self` to be equal to your `SayHello` instance instead of the `main` object.

I Googled for "ruby change self for a block" and found [a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9460736/how-to-change-self-in-a-block-like-instance-eval-method-do) which makes me think you should change your code to:

```
class SayHello
  def initialize(&p)
    @message = "Hello."
    instance_eval(&p) if block_given?
  end

  def say_it
    puts @message
  end
end

SayHello.new { say_it }
```

Comment: What's the difference between `&p` and `yield`?

Comment: `&p` captures the method's block as a proc, which you can then pass to `instance_eval` in order to change its `self`. `yield` just passes control the block and only returns it once the block is done.

Comment: Yeah `yield` runs the block and returns its value, `&p` basically is the block.